# How to change the class of all li of current ul?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have 1 ul with various class of li.

```
<ul class="" style="margin: 0 0 0 5px;">
    <li>
        <aclass="cam_title">
        Couple Watches</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="cam_title">
        Titan Men's Watches</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="cam_title">
        Timex Men</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hidden_camaign" style="display:none;">
        <a>Casio Men</a>
    </li><li class="hidden_camaign" style="display:none;">
        <a>Casio women</a>
    </li><li class="hidden_camaign" style="display:none;">
        <a>Casio unisex</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="see_more" href="javascript">See more</a></li> 
</ul>
```

I want on `$( '.see_more' ).click(function(){`
do change the class to show_campaign of all li which has class hidden_campaign
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want toggling effect in jQuery. So better to use `slideToggle` function which also give you smooth transition effect. As well as you also want to change the text of the link. Here is the solution.

```
$('.see_more').click(function () {
   var btn = $(this);
   $(this).closest('li').siblings('.hidden_camaign').slideToggle('slow', function () {
      if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
         $(btn).text('See Less');
      }
      else {
         $(btn).text('See more');
      }
   })
});
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv5CQ/)**

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.closest()`, `.siblings()` and `.toggleClass()` to achieve what you want.

Try,

```
 $( '.see_more' ).click(function(){ 
   $(this).closest('li').siblings('.hidden_camaign').toggleClass('hidden_camaign show_campaign');
 });
```

Comment: yeah I think OP is looking for toggle function. and also I think the text should be toggling between `see more` and `see less`.. if it is so.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
$('.see_more' ).click(function(){ 
   $(this).closest('ul').find('.hidden_camaign').removeClass('hidden_camaign').addClass('show_campaign ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access using the parent ul and its child selectors for your requirement

```
$( '.see_more' ).click(function(){
    $(this).parent("ul").find("li.hidden_camaign").addClass("show_camaign").removeClass("hidden_camaign");

    });
```